# How to disable Flareget from Firefox?

Tags: firefox

Hello I want to disable flareget from mozilla firefox. Whenever I click on some download button flareget starts downloading the file. But I want to download by the browser downloader.

Comment: Why don't you just uninstall flareget if you don't want to use it?

Comment: I want to use it, but not always.

Answer (score 0):

In firefox, Tools > Flashgot > More options > tab General > first field;

Change it back to wget.